# Scikit learn cross validation split

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I'm currently using **cross_validation.cross_val_predict** to obtain the predictions made by a LogisticRegression classifier. My question is: what percentage of the data makes up the training set and what percentage makes up the test set? Is it an 80%-20% split?

I checked the website and other questions on stackoverflow but did not find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation for this function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_predict.html#sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_predict), it states for the `cv` arg:

> cv : cross-validation generator or int, optional, default: None
>   A cross-validation generator to use. If int, determines the number of folds in StratifiedKFold if y is binary or multiclass and estimator is a classifier, or the number of folds in KFold otherwise. If None, it is equivalent to cv=3. This generator must include all elements in the test set exactly once. Otherwise, a ValueError is raised.

Comment: Yes, but they don't state what percentage of the data goes into the test set in each fold.

Comment: Nope, I think it does: 1/3rd.

Comment: Alright, I guess it makes sense. That how I do it usually but I read in some places that they do it differently. Anyway, thank you!